# Issue IKEV1 for Libreswan 3.27 : no connection has been authorized with policy PSK+IKEV1_ALLOW

Tags: vpn, ipsec, libreswan

I'm trying to connect to a Cisco ASA 5520. I have been provided credentials :

```
Phase1
VPN IP address (Public IP)       | XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
Authentication Method            | Pre-Shared Secret
Encryption Schema                | IKE
Perfect Forward Secrecy- IKE     | DH Group-2
Encryption Algorithm             | 3DES
Hashing Algorithm                | SHA-1
Renegotiate IKE SA every         | 86400 Sec

Phase2
IPSec                            | ESP
Perfect Forward Secrecy-IPSEC    | NO PFS
Encryption Algorithm IPSec       | 3DES
Hashing Algorithm IPSec          | SHA-1
Renegotiate IPSec SA every       | 3600 Sec  
Private Network                  | 192.168.XXX.XXX/32
```

On my side, I compiled and installed Libreswan (3.27) on a DigitalOcean droplet, with the public **IP : YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY** and a private **IP: 10.YYY.YYY.YYY/32**. I tried to implement the IPSec VPN with this config:

```
conn the_vpn
  ike=3des-sha1;modp1024,aes128-sha1;modp1024
  auto=start
  authby=secret
  keyexchange=ike
  phase2=esp
  phase2alg=3des-sha1
  left=XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  leftsubnet=192.168.XXX.XXX/32
  right=YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
  rightsubnet=10.YYY.YYY.YYY/32
  ikelifetime=3600
  type=tunnel
  ikev2=never
```

And I did allow `udp` on port `500` and `4500` in my server (Ubuntu 16.04). I also wrote down the secrekey in `/etc/ipsec.secrets`. But through the logs; it seems that the handshake is initialized by the CISCO, but my side has this error:

`packet from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:500 : initial Main Mode message received on YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY:500  but no connection has been authorized with policy PSK+IKEV1_ALLOW`

My question are these:

1) does Libreswan still allow IKEV1 with shared PSK and DH 2 group or it has been deprecated and removed ?

2) does my configurations reflect the other side ? Because, as usual, It's me who has to conform to their setup, they can't change anything.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DH2 support has been removed. For IKEv1, the minimum is DH5. For IKEv2, the minimum is DH14

See also RFC 8247 which declares DH2 as MUST NOT implement.
(note - better ask on the swan list next time for faster response)